# Include property from middle table when using Has Many Through

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

```
places
    id - integer

place_details
    id - integer
    place_id - integer
    category_id - integer
    is_primary - boolean

place_categories
    id - integer
    name - string
```

`category_id` in `place_details` is a foreign key for `id` in `place_categories`.

Using `place_id` in `places`, I need to retrieve a list of all `place_categories`. This requires HasManyThrough, which I've used here:

```
class Place extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'place';

    protected $with = [
        'categories',
    ];

    public function placeDetails(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PlaceDetails::class, 'place_id', 'place_id');
    }

    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PlaceCategory::class, PlaceDetailsCategory::class, 'place_id', 'category_id', 'place_id', 'id')
            ->withPivot('is_primary');
    }
}
```

This works, however it currently returns something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Text",
    "laravel_through_key": 77,
    "pivot": {
        "place_id": 77,
        "category_id": 12,
        "is_primary": 0
    }
}
```

But I'd like it to return:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Text",
    "laravel_through_key": 77,
    "is_primary": 0
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your JsonResource of this